# How can I improve this circuit design?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter

I am building a solar powered lego catapult for my science fair project. I am trying to build a simple and efficient DC motor circuit that maximizes the power of solar panels to the DC motor (the catapult should be able to lift and throw something like a football). Here's my schematic below, I'm not sure whether if a capacitor (C1) is used correctly, I'm using them to make the current flow fast. (Also is this capacitor (C1) is necessary for this circuit?) I don't know if a flyback diode will have any effect on the lego motor when turned off since it contains a mini startup capacitor. Any ideas? Can you guys please give me tips and suggestions on how to improve my circuit design? My physics knowledge are limited to high school level.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fECf4T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the boost converter above steps 3V up to 6V. This is my first time using circuitlab sorry if it looks confusing to you.

Comment: Are you thinking about a Lego compatible football or a human size foot ball?  A huge difference in power requirements here.

Comment: human size football, also the load can also be something that weight less than that football

Comment: You need the formula to compare energy storage of 1F Cap, 10kF battery (Li Ion) a coil spring, gravity to understand what to choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large cap (C1) would not normally be needed if you are just driving a simple DC motor. Similarly the flyback diode may not be needed if the motor is the only part being run in the circuit.

What is the idea to have the current flow fast? In your diagram the 220uF capacitor discharging into a simple DC motor would only power it for a very short time, likely not enough time to do anything useful. To get at least some useful motor run time you might need what is called a super cap. These can have several Farads of capacity.

The only m-motor that saw related to lego kits are those used for example to slowly spin something like a ferris wheel made of legos. If you are thinking about a catapult that can be slowly pulled back then perhaps your ideal would work for such a system.  However if you want to launch a football at the instant you switch the system on you are going to need a much stronger motor.

Also keep in mind that when using a voltage step up module the input current needs to be higher then the expected output current.  You get the voltage increase but at the expense of a lower output current. For example if you want a 6V output near 500ma you would need to have at least a 1000ma input at 3V). That much current might require a moderate size solar cell array, (you would need to check the supplier's specifications), it may need to be several square inches or more, (plus a very bright light over it).

Your science project likely has safety rules. Might I suggest that you think more in the line of a "Nerf" football throwing system? That would be fairly safe and require much less power. Even with that there could still be some safety concerns related to a catapult's swinging mechanism.

For the connection to the catapult I would suggest something like a string being slowly wound on the motor shaft or possible a rubber band that is slowly wound tight. The catapult is then operated by cutting the string or by opening a mechanical latch holding back the catapult's lever.

For a final idea: There are descriptions/plans on the internet for building repeating catapults (or roman ballista), that are driven by continued cranking. A DC motor might work well on something like this. Of course only use safe projectiles like foam footballs, (or other "Nerf toys").

Good luck with you science project.

Comment: I heard that including the flyback diode in the circuit prevents a charge buildup damage to the motor when the switch is open (turning off the circuit). Since you are suggesting me to remove the diode, I wonder will the LEGO motor will be damaged when I open the switch without the diode.

Comment: Yes, store the energy mechanically in the catapult. It takes about 4 joules to raise a real football 1 meter. An XL motor puts out 1.7 W. Assuming 50% mechanical efficiency, it would take 5 seconds to "charge" the spring catapult. I can't find the specs for the M-motor, but somewhere I read that it is about half as powerful. So, if you need to use an M-motor, double the time.

Comment: Don't undersize your solar cell. Their specs are for ideal conditions, strong sun hitting perpendicular. Get a 20W at least, don't fail because you didn't have enough light.

Comment: I would guess that is very unlikely.  From what I've seen these are low power motors that wouldn't give much of an inductive kick back.  If it were that important the mfgr would likely have installed one internal to the assembly.  With that said, if you were to add extra circuitry that connects to the motor then an extra diode in that position could help reduce noise in the rest of the system. A solenoid component would more often have a flyback diode in such a position as these can have a higher inductance, deal with higher currents, and have higher voltage spikes..

Comment: Suppose when I replace 220uF capacitor with 1F capacitor, how will that affect motor performance at startup?

Comment: @Jimmy Yang - You could start to get a few seconds of run time if using very large capacitors. But also remember that when discharging a capacitor the voltage level drops off quickly, so the motor might give a few normal speed spins but then slow down quickly.